Changing the exception type in a context manager
I currently have code that looks like this scattered throughout my codebase:
try: 
    something()
except Exception as exc:
    raise SomethingError from exc

I would like to write a context manager that would remove some of this boiler-plate:
with ExceptionWrapper(SomethingError):
    something()

It looks like it is possible to suppress exceptions inside a context manager - see: contextlib.suprress.  It doesn't look like it is possible to change what exception is being raised.
However, I haven't been able to find clear documentation on what the return value of the __exit__ function of a context manager is.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.exit says "Exceptions that occur during execution of this method will replace any exception that occurred in the body of the with statement."

This sort of simple context manager is easiest to implement using contextlib.contextmanager, which creates a context manager out of a generator. Simply wrap the first yield statement in the generator with a try block and raise the desired exception in the except block:
import contextlib
from typing import Iterator


class SomethingError(Exception):
    pass


@contextlib.contextmanager
def exception_wrapper(message: str) -> Iterator[None]:
    """Wrap Exceptions with SomethingError."""
    try: 
        yield
    except Exception as exc:
        raise SomethingError(message) from exc

This can be used like so:
>>> with exception_wrapper("and eggs!"):
...     raise Exception("spam")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 11, in exception_wrapper
    yield
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise Exception("spam")
Exception: spam

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 16, in <module>
    with exception_wrapper("and eggs!"):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/path/to/script.py", line 13, in exception_wrapper
    raise SomethingError(message) from exc
__main__.SomethingError: and eggs!

